# Solve equation with a constraint parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation for `phi`:

```
phi[x_] := (Sin[beta*x/l] - Sinh[beta*x/l]) + 
   gamma[beta]*(Cos[beta*x/l] - Cosh[beta*x/l] - 
      beta*la/(2*l)*Sinh[beta*x/l]);
```

where `gamma` can be expressed in terms of `beta`:

```
gamma[beta_] := (Sinh[beta] - Sin[beta])/(Cos[beta] - Cosh[beta] - 
     beta*la/(2*l)*Sinh[beta]);
```

and `beta`satisfies the following equation:

```
(k*l/(e*i))^2 + (k*
     l/(e*i))*(2*
      beta*(Sin[beta]*Cosh[beta] - Cos[beta]*Sinh[beta]))/(1 - 
      Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) + (2*beta^2*Sin[beta]*Sinh[beta])/(1 - 
     Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) == 0
```

Now, I am wodering, **how I can calulate `phi[x]`if all numeric parameters are given ?**

For example:

```
param={k->2,e->3,i->4,l->2,la->5};
```

Essentially all the difficulty is to determine beta...

*How I tried to do it:*

```
NSolve[(k*l/(e*i))^2 + (k*
 l/(e*i))*(2*
  beta*(Sin[beta]*Cosh[beta] - Cos[beta]*Sinh[beta]))/(1 - 
  Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) + (2*beta^2*Sin[beta]*Sinh[beta])/(1 - 
 Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) == 0 /.param, beta]
```

... but I could not find beta.

I guess that the diffculty arises from the fact that there are a mutlitude of different solutions for beta:

```
p1 = Plot[(k*l/(e*i))^2 + (k*
        l/(e*i))*(2*
         beta*(Sin[beta]*Cosh[beta] - Cos[beta]*Sinh[beta]))/(1 - 
         Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) /. param, {beta, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];

p2 = Plot[-(2*beta^2*Sin[beta]*Sinh[beta])/(1 - 
       Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) /. param, {beta, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green];
```

The solutions are the intersections of the red and the green curve:
[image]

Comment: Which beta do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the range of beta.

```
NSolve[(((k*l/(e*i))^2 + (k*
       l/(e*i))*(2*
        beta*(Sin[beta]*Cosh[beta] - Cos[beta]*Sinh[beta]))/(1 - 
        Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) + (2*beta^2*Sin[beta]*
       Sinh[beta])/(1 - Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) == 0 /. param) // 
    TrigReduce) && -10 < beta < 10, beta]

(*   {{beta -> -9.4594}, {beta -> -6.33444}, {beta -> -3.23973}, {beta -> 
                 3.23973}, {beta -> 6.33444}, {beta -> 9.4594}}   *)
```

Comment: First I tried your approach without `//TrigReduce` and MMA doesn't finish evaluation. Tricky!

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you understand why it does not work without TigReduce ?

Comment: @james: No idea...

Comment: okay, I see. no problem

Comment: With  `-10 < beta < 10 ` you force NSolve to work only wtih real beta. Then it happens, it does not find negative solutions. I think the algorithm of NSolve needs intermediate complex calculation, even if results are all real. With  `TrigReduce ` you introduce e.g. `Cos[(1 + I) beta] ` complex expressions and algorthm can work well. When you apply `Abs[beta] < 10 `  instead and without `TrigReduce ` , it is also allowed to work in the complexes and finds all real solutions plus complex one (which you later can delete).

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

A tricky way to find all the solutions for beta in the range `-10<beta<10`

```
param = {k -> 2, e -> 3, i -> 4, l -> 2, la -> 5};
gl = (k*l/(e*i))^2 + (k*
   l/(e*i))*(2*
    beta*(Sin[beta]*Cosh[beta] - Cos[beta]*Sinh[beta]))/(1 - 
    Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) + (2*beta^2*Sin[beta]*Sinh[beta])/(1 - 
   Cos[beta]*Cosh[beta]) == 0  /. param;
```

is using Plot & "GraphicsMeshFindIntersections"

```
bild = Plot[{gl, 0}, {beta, -10, 10}]
betai = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[bild[[All, 1]]][[All, 1]]
(* {-9.45877, -6.33444, -3.23962, 3.23933, 6.33438, 9.45937} *)
```

and substitute this result in the definitiion `phi[x]`

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is a nice way to do it.

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly you do when you type: `bild[[All, 1]]][[All, 1]` in `GraphicsMeshFindIntersections` ?

Comment: @james bild is a Graphics-object and bild[[All,1]] gives the different curves you plotted. GarphicsMeshFindIntersections evaluates the intersection point{{beta1, ...},{beta2, ...},...} and the last [[All,1]] just take the beta's .